# Jquery remove next of next div element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have structure like

```
<div id="fileuploader1" style="display: none;">Upload Your Pic</div>
<div id="error"></div>
<div class="ajax-file-upload-statusbar">blabla 1</div>


<div id="fileuploader2" style="display: none;">Upload Your Pic</div>
<div id="error"></div>
<div class="ajax-file-upload-statusbar">blablas 2</div>
```

So with element `fileuploader1` I must remove `<div class="ajax-file-upload-statusbar">blabla 1</div>`

And with element `fileuploader2` I must remove `<div class="ajax-file-upload-statusbar">blabla 2</div>`

I tried something like below

```
$('#fileuploader1').next().next().remove();
```

I need to remove only if next of next div is ajax-file-upload-statusbar

Comment: `$('.ajax-file-upload-statusbar').remove();`

Comment: this will remove both the div

Comment: then use @Mateusz Mania answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87gpf2es/)

```
if($('#fileuploader1').next().next().hasClass('ajax-file-upload-statusbar')){

     $('#fileuploader1').next().next().remove();
}
```

**Shorter version:**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87gpf2es/1/)

```
$('#fileuploader1').nextAll('.ajax-file-upload-statusbar').remove();
```

**Shortest version:**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87gpf2es/2/)

```
$('#fileuploader1++.ajax-file-upload-statusbar').remove();
```

Comment: Btw. i have shortest version.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do:

```
$('#fileuploader1').next().next('.ajax-file-upload-statusbar').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using hashtag (#) for id selector, not (.):

```
 $('#fileuploader1').next().next().remove();
```

Comment: how to remove only if next of next class is ajax-file-upload-statusbar

Comment: $('#fileuploader1').next().next('.ajax-file-upload-statusbar').remove();